# How to do a FIFO push-operation for rows on Pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to maintain a Pandas dataframe with 500 rows, and as the next row becomes available I want to push that new row in and throw out the oldest row from the dataframe. e.g. Let's say I maintain row 0 as newest, and row 500 as oldest. When I get a new data, I would push data to row 0, and it will shift row 0 to row 1, and so on until it pushes row 499 to row 500 (and row 500 gets deleted).

Is there a way to do such a FIFO operation on Pandas? Thanks guys!

Comment: 1. do you mean, that you read data from a fifo? 2. using dataframe as a queue is very inefficient, because it takes O(N) time to insert/remove a row in your scenario. Just use a queue.

Comment: You could `df.shift(1); df.loc[0] = new_row`. That'll be slow tho.

Comment: @JohnGalt, yes sir! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnGalt `df.shift(1); df.iloc[0] = new_row`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@JohnGalt posted an answer to this on the comments. Thanks a lot. I just wanted to put the answer here just in case if people are looking for similar information in the future.

`df.shift(1) df.loc[0] = new_row`

`df.shift(n)` will shift the rows `n` times, filling the first `n` rows with `na` and getting rid of last `n` rows. The number of rows of `df` will not change with `df.shift`.

I hope this is helpful.