# How to count pairs inside a dataframe using python and pandas

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, count

My data in excel look like this.

[image]

fi denote some features, IDi denotes customer IDs and the numbers denote the
times that a certain feature appeared.

I would like to count the pairs of features that appear together in these IDs and come up with some like this
[image]

This matrix is to be interpreted in the following way:
(f1,f2) appeared three times together (in ID2,ID3,ID4)
(f2,f3) appeared one time together (in ID3)
(f1,f4) appeared 3 times together (in ID1, ID2, ID3) and so on

This is my jupyter
[image]

Comment: depending on how you had structured the data in the python code, a for loop with multiple pair check counter should do.

Comment: The dataframe will look like in the first picture. Thank you for your advice, feel free to share code as well

Comment: I mean, in your code (please share).. how does table 1 is defined ? Plus, what variable/datafram structure d u  use to store the (f1,f2), (f2,f3) etc pairs ? [ You only share how your data (table 1) look like in excel.. not how it was captured in your  code (dataframe variable name/numbering). ]

Comment: I imported this excel in jupyter notebook using : 

df=pd.read("data.xlsx", engine="openpyxyl")
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df.set_index("Features",inplace=True) 

IDs appear as headers and features f1,f2... appear as indexes

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
print(df)

# convert to binary

df2=df
for i in range(4) :
    for j in range(1,5) :
        if df2.iloc[i,j] > 0 :
            df2.iloc[i,j] = 1
print(df2)

ar=df2.iloc[:,1:].values # extract f1-f4 array values | ref#2

df3 = df2
df3.rename(columns = {'ID1':'f1','ID2':'f2','ID3':'f3','ID4':'f4'}, inplace = True ) # ref#1

for i in range(4) :
    for j in range(1,5) :
        if i == (j-1) :
            df3.iloc[i,j] = 0
        else : 
            df3.iloc[i,j] = sum(ar[i]*ar[j-1]) # found out that df*df didn't work.
            
print(df3)
```

`dfa = dfb` is decieving.. it actually works like a pointer, not variable. print df2 & df and you can see. `df2=df` just shares the reference, it's not initiating new variable . That's why `df = sum(df*df)` didn't work.

Please have a try, and share if its work/understandable/not.

Ref :

[1] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-rename-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/

[2] [Pandas dataframe , using iloc to replace last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644442/pandas-dataframe-using-iloc-to-replace-last-row)